# Client/Server Socket Java (pattern MVC) doesn't send correct information to the Client

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm writing a game but now I'm a problem with server/client socket. The game works well when I play in local and also when I play online with RMI. The problem there is when I try to implements the socket (I must do also socket). This is how I've implemented  the code (I use the pattern Model-View-Controller):

SERVER:
Class SocketServerCreate: create the server and then create a Thread to receive the connection (SocketServerConnection) that then create another Thread to receive the message by all the client (SocketServerReceive). The Server instantiate also an object that implements Observer that is called by the model to send information to the client (SocketServerOutput).

CLIENT:
Class SocketClientCreate: open the connection with the server, then create a Thread to receive message by the server and instantiate a class that implements Observer that is called by the view to send information to the Server.

The problem is that the update method of the Server that is in the class SocketServerOutput is called a lot of time, but it must be called only one time to send the message to the client. To be clare I post all the code of the Server and the Client.

**SocketServerCreate**

```
/*
 * This class creates the server.
 */

public class SocketServerCreate {

private static final int PORT = 5000;
private ArrayList<ObjectOutputStream> arrayPlayerSocket;
private SocketServerOutput outputServer;

public SocketServerCreate(Model model){

    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    Controller controller = new Controller(model);
    arrayPlayerSocket = new ArrayList<ObjectOutputStream>();
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error during the creation of the Server.\n" +     e.getStackTrace());
        return;
    }

    outputServer = new SocketServerOutput(this, controller);

    SocketServerConnection connectionServer = new SocketServerConnection(this, serverSocket, controller);
    Thread receiveServerThread = new Thread(connectionServer);
    receiveServerThread.start();

}

public void addPlayerSocket(ObjectOutputStream outputStream){
    arrayPlayerSocket.add(outputStream);
}

public ArrayList<ObjectOutputStream> getArrayPlayerSocket(){
    return (ArrayList<ObjectOutputStream>) arrayPlayerSocket;
}

public SocketServerOutput getSocketServerOutput(){
    return outputServer;
}

}
```

**SocketServerOutput**

```
/*
 * This class manages the object that must be send to the client.
 */

public class SocketServerOutput implements Observer {

ArrayList<ObjectOutputStream> arrayPlayersSocket;
SocketServerCreate socketServerCreate;
Controller controller;
private ObjectOutputStream outputMessage = null;

public SocketServerOutput(SocketServerCreate socketServerCreate, Controller controller){
    this.socketServerCreate = socketServerCreate;
    this.controller = controller;
}


@Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {

    if(o.equals(controller.getModel().getModelChanges())){
        arrayPlayersSocket = socketServerCreate.getArrayPlayerSocket();
        Iterator<ObjectOutputStream> arrayIterator = arrayPlayersSocket.iterator();
        while(arrayIterator.hasNext()){
            outputMessage = (ObjectOutputStream)arrayIterator.next();
            try {
                outputMessage.writeObject(arg);
                outputMessage.flush();
                /*if(arrayPlayersSocket.indexOf(outputMessage) != controller.getTurn().getCurrentPlayer()){
                    ModelChanges modelChanges = new ModelChanges();
                    modelChanges.spegniBottoniOnLine(false, false, false);
                    outputMessage.writeObject(modelChanges);
                    outputMessage.flush();
                }*/
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("IOException while the server sends an object to the client!");
                return;
            }

        }

    }

}



}
```

**SocketServerConnection**

```
    public class SocketServerConnection implements Runnable {

private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private SocketServerCreate socketServerCreate;
private Controller controller;

public SocketServerConnection(SocketServerCreate socketServerCreate, ServerSocket serverSocket, Controller controller){

    this.socketServerCreate = socketServerCreate;
    this.serverSocket = serverSocket;
    this.controller = controller;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    while(true){

        try {
            Socket lastSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            ObjectOutputStream outputMessage = new ObjectOutputStream(lastSocket.getOutputStream());
            socketServerCreate.addPlayerSocket(outputMessage);
             //send to the view the index where the client is setted in the server array
            outputMessage.writeObject((Integer)socketServerCreate.getArrayPlayerSocket().lastIndexOf(outputMessage));
            outputMessage.flush();
            SocketServerReceive receiveServer = new SocketServerReceive(lastSocket, controller);
            Thread receiveThread = new Thread(receiveServer);
            receiveThread.start();  
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException while the server accept the client.\n" + e.getCause());
        }


    }

}

}
```

**SocketServerReceive**

```
public class SocketServerReceive implements Runnable {

private ObjectInputStream inputMessage = null;
private Controller controller;
private Object message;

public SocketServerReceive(Socket socket, Controller controller){
    this.controller = controller;
    System.out.println("Connection created with the client that has IP Address: " + socket.getInetAddress());

    if(inputMessage == null){
        try {
            inputMessage = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException while the server are creating a stream with the client.\n" + e.getCause());
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void run() {

    while(true){
        try {
            message = inputMessage.readObject();
            controller.receiveMessageView(message);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException in SocketServerReceive.\n" + e.getStackTrace());
            return;
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }

}

}
```

**SocketClientCreate**

```
/*
 * This class starts a connection with the Server and then it creates two threads,
 * one to manage the input request, the other to manage the output request
 */

public class SocketClientCreate {

private static final int PORT = 5000;
private Socket serverSocket;
private int arrayIndex;
private SocketClientOutput outputClient;

public SocketClientCreate(String ipAddress, View view){

    try {
        serverSocket = new Socket(ipAddress, PORT);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.out.println("UnknownHostException during the connection of the Client at the Server");
        return;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException during the connection of the Client at the Server");
        return;
    }

    outputClient = new SocketClientOutput(this, serverSocket, view);


    SocketClientReceive receiveClient = new SocketClientReceive(this, serverSocket, view);
    Thread receiveThread = new Thread(receiveClient);
    receiveThread.start();

}

public SocketClientOutput getOutputClient(){
    return outputClient;
}

public void setArrayIndex (Integer arrayIndex){
    this.arrayIndex = arrayIndex;
}

public int getArrayIndex(){
    return arrayIndex;
}

}
```

**SocketClientOutput**

```
/*
 * This class manages all the message that the client must send to the server. Its methods 
 * are called by update method.
 */

public class SocketClientOutput implements Observer {

private ObjectOutputStream outputMessage = null;
private View view;
private SocketClientCreate socketClientCreate;

public SocketClientOutput(SocketClientCreate socketClientCreate, Socket server, View view){

    this.view = view;
    this.socketClientCreate = socketClientCreate;
    if(outputMessage == null){
        try {
            outputMessage = new ObjectOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException at the opening of the output stream between the client and the server.\n" + e.getCause());
            return;
        }
    }

}

/*
 * update receive an object from the view and send this object to the server.
 */
@Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {

    if(o.equals(view)){
        /*
         * GESTIRE INDICE CREAZIONE GIOCATORE
         */
        try {
            outputMessage.writeObject(arg);
            outputMessage.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException while the client sends an object to the server.\n" + e.getCause());
            return;
        }

    }

}

}
```

**SocketClientReceive**

```
/*
 * This class waits an object from the server and then modify the view.
 */

public class SocketClientReceive implements Runnable {

private ObjectInputStream inputMessage = null;
private View view;
private SocketClientCreate socketClientCreate;
private Object message;

public SocketClientReceive(SocketClientCreate socketClientCreate, Socket server, View view){

    this.view = view;
    this.socketClientCreate = socketClientCreate;
    if(inputMessage == null){
        try {
            inputMessage = new ObjectInputStream(server.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException at the opening of the input stream between the client and the server.\n"+e.getStackTrace());
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void run() {

    while(true){
        try {
            message = inputMessage.readObject();
            if(message instanceof Integer){
                socketClientCreate.setArrayIndex((Integer)message);
            }else if(message instanceof ModelChanges){
                ModelChanges modelChanges = (ModelChanges)message;
                view.getMappa().repaintView(modelChanges);
            }

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException waiting a message from the server!\n"+e.getStackTrace());
            return;
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to create a boolean, that is enabled by default, but turn false when the server sends a message. Then, when the server intends to send another message, turn it should turn true. Contact me if this was what you had in mind, or if you are looking for something else.

```
        private Object lastMessage;
        private boolean hasSentMessage;

        @Override
        public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        //Check if the message is the same as the last message.
        if(!arg.equals(lastMessage))
            hasSentMessage = false;

        //Also check if it has already sent a message.
        if(o.equals(controller.getModel().getModelChanges()) && !hasSentMessage){
            arrayPlayersSocket = socketServerCreate.getArrayPlayerSocket();
            Iterator<ObjectOutputStream> arrayIterator = arrayPlayersSocket.iterator();
            while(arrayIterator.hasNext()){
                outputMessage = (ObjectOutputStream)arrayIterator.next();
                try {
                    outputMessage.writeObject(arg);
                    outputMessage.flush();

                    //State that the message has been sent.
                    hasSentMessage = true;
                    lastMessage = arg;

                    /*if(arrayPlayersSocket.indexOf(outputMessage) != controller.getTurn().getCurrentPlayer()){
                        ModelChanges modelChanges = new ModelChanges();
                        modelChanges.spegniBottoniOnLine(false, false, false);
                        outputMessage.writeObject(modelChanges);
                        outputMessage.flush();
                    }*/
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("IOException while the server sends an object to the client!");
                    return;
                }

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I can't use this way because the model sends the same object but with different variable. there is a way to use this method but adapting it with my situation?